# approximation of $\pi$ by $\arctan$

Tags: approximation, taylor-expansion

Determinate the order n of the Maclaurin polynomial for $f(x)=4tan^{-1}x$ so that the remainader term $|R_{n}(1)|<0.000005$.
Here $R_{n}(1)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}$ for some c between 0 and 1
How can I estimate $f^{(n+1)}(c)$, it seem that the derivatives of f have no pattern

Comment: You have the explicit series. You can estimate the remainder from that. (If you are not afraid of complex numbers, you can do a partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, then you get a relatively simple expression for the derivatives.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the alternating series
$$4\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1},$$
you can use the Alternating Series Remainder Theorem.  The remainder of your series is bounded by $|a_{n+1}|$ where $a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}.$

So all you need to do is solve the inequality
$$\frac{4}{2n+3}\le\frac{1}{200000},$$
giving $n\ge 200000.$  (Yes it is a VERY slowly converging series!)

Of course, this is the series centered around $x=0.$  It will change (drastically) if you are wanting to center the polynomial around $x=1.$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives a series around $x=1$ which is quite a bit more complicated http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power+series+arctan%28x%29+about+x%3D1.